# Do local variables need to be synchronized?

Tags: c#, variables, thread-synchronization

When multiple threads access data simultaneously, access must be synchronized to prevent data integrity problems. Do local variables need to be synchronized?

Comment: If they are accessed from multiple threads then yes. Usually in this case they are not technically local variables but fields (because were captured by some closure).

Comment: No, I would think not.

Comment: Depends on how they are used.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if you gave a specific example. If by "access data" you mean read data that is immutable then, no, but otherwise probably.

Answer (score 5):

> When multiple threads access data simultaneously, access must be synchronized to prevent data integrity problems. Do local variables need to be synchronized?

The question indicates that you're thinking about the problem in the wrong way. Once you start thinking about things correctly, you won't need to ask the question anymore.

Let's start by removing the errors in your question.

> When multiple threads access data simultaneously, access must be synchronized to prevent data integrity problems.

This is a common characterization but it is subtly incorrect because it is too weak. The correct way to characterize the situation is:

- Reads and writes of storage on multiple threads may be observed to happen in an order other than the order that would be implied by a sequential execution of each line of code.
- **There is no requirement that a globally consistent ordering be observed by any thread**.  Two threads can disagree as to whether a read precedes or follows a write.
- Since reads and writes may be observed to happen in different orders on different threads **the whole idea that things happen simultaneously is not useful**.
- The C# specification restricts the valid reorderings of certain kinds of reads and writes with respect to each other, and with respect to certain other "special events" such as taking a lock, ending a thread, throwing an exception, and so on.  See the C# specification for details.

So it is not:

> When multiple threads access data simultaneously, access must be synchronized to prevent data integrity problems.

In the crazy world of multithreaded code, problems can arise that have nothing to do with simultaneous access or data integrity. Rather, it would be more accurate to say:

> When multiple threads do read and write operations on memory, those reads and writes can be observed to be in unexpected orders and at unexpected times which violate program invariants *unless synchronization primitives are used to restrict the valid reorderings to those which preserve program invariants*.

Now the answer to your question is clear:

> Do local variables need to be synchronized?

*If reads and writes of local variables must be observed to happen in a particular order with respect to special events in order to preserve program invariants*, and the desired order is not already guaranteed by the C# specification, then, like all reads and writes from memory, they must use synchronization primitives to achieve the desired order.

Do not fall into the trap that some other answers have of saying that "locals are on the stack" -- they are not necessarily on the short term pool!  Locals are only allocated on the short term pool *when their lifetimes are shorter than the activation of the method*, and *when method activations logically form a stack*.  Locals which are closed-over locals of a lambda have long lifetimes, and locals in iterator blocks or async methods are in methods whose activations do not form a stack.

And besides, who cares? *Stack memory can be shared across threads using unsafe code.*

Also do not fall into the trap of thinking that some locals are "real locals" and some are "fake locals".  The defining characteristic of a local is that *its name has local scope*, not that *it has short lifetime*.  Locals are not guaranteed to have short lifetimes in C#.

Here are just some ways that a local can be accessed on multiple threads:

- The local is in an iterator block; the `IEnumerator` can be accessed on multiple threads. Note that this will almost certainly die horribly; iterator blocks are not designed to be safe in these conditions.
- The local is in an async method which resumes on a thread other than the thread which awaited. Though this does not involve access "at the same time", who cares? The fundamental problem is not whether a local can be accessed at the same time, but rather whether reads and writes of the local are observed to be in a particular order with respect to special events.
- The local is a closed-over local of a lambda or anonymous method; the delegate (or compiled expression tree) can be invoked on multiple threads.  Use caution! This is easy to do with the Task Parallel Library.
- The local is an unmanaged type; a pointer to the local is passed to multiple threads, which can now read or write to it.  **This can happen even if the local is "on the stack"**.  Of course, when you use unsafe code, **the safety system is off and you are responsible for ensuring safety**.  That's why it's called "unsafe".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if accessed in parallel:

```
private List<int> GetInts()
{
    var res = new List<int>();
    Parallel.For(0,100, i=>
    {
        lock(res)
        {
            res.Add(i);
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This is always a fun example because *at the IL level* `res` is no longer a "local" - it is a public field. In terms of C# - I guess "captured variable", so again: not really a "local"

Comment: Wow, this is very valuable piece of information. Should look what is generated. Thanks!

Comment: it will create a private class (with a horrible name) with a public field called `res` and a method (with a horrible name) with the `lock(res) { res.Add(i); }` code; then `GetInts` is basically: `var _blah = new TheTypeName(); _blah.res = new List<int>(); Parallel.For(0, 100, _blah.TheMehtodName); return _blah.res;`